# Laravel 5.4 Eloquent not Saving certain fields

Tags: laravel, eloquent, observers

I have been working on logging all user activities in Model events... But for some reason, the records are stored in the user_action table but the action_model field. This is my code.
User Action Class
`

```
class UserAction extends Model
{

  use SoftDeletes;

  protected $table = 'user_actions';

  /**
  *
  */

  protected $fillable = [
      'user_id','action', ' action_model', 'action_id'
  ];

  public function user()
  {
      return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
  }



}
```

`

UserActionObervable

```
    class UserActionObserver
{
    public function saved($model)
    {
        $type = $model->getTable();
        // dd($type); when dump the value exists
        if ($model->wasRecentlyCreated == true) {
            // Data was just created
            $action = 'created';
        } else {
            // Data was updated
            $action = 'updated';
        }
        if (Sentinel::check()) {
            UserAction::create([
                'user_id'      => Sentinel::getUser()->id,
                'action'       => $action,
                'action_model' => 'model', //I tried to pass in constant
                'action_id'    => $model->id
            ]);
        }
    }

    public function deleting($model)
    {
        if (Sentinel::check()) {
            UserAction::create([
                'user_id'      => Sentinel::getUser()->id,
                'action'       => 'deleted',
                'action_model' => $model->getTable(),
                'action_id'    => $model->id
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the schema

```
Schema::create('user_actions', function (Blueprint $table) {
      $table->increments('id');
      $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
      $table->string('action');  // created / updated / deleted
      $table->string('action_model');
      $table->integer('action_id')->nullable(); 
      $table->timestamps();

      $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
      $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')
            ->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');

    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
protected $fillable = [
    'user_id','action', ' action_model', 'action_id'
];
```

Try to remove the space before `action_model`. The field in `$fillable` doesn't match the key you're passing into the `create()` method.

Comment: syntax errors... It's just killing me...Thanks, I wouldn't have noticed for the next 10 hours probably

Comment: eagle eyes ... :)